# How to construct a differential equation of this problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, word-problem

A tank containing water is in the form of a cone with vertex C. The axis is vertical and the semi-vertical angle is 60°.

At time t= 0, the tank is full and the depth of water is H. At this instant, a tap at C is opened and water begins to flow out.

The volume of water in the tank decreases at a rate proportional to $\sqrt h$, where h is the depth of water at time t.

The tank becomes empty when t=$60$. Find h at time t in terms of H and t.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = k\sqrt{h}
$$
$$
r = h\tan\theta
$$

$$
dV = \pi r^2 dh = \pi(h\tan\theta)^2dh \therefore \frac{dV}{dt}= \pi(h\tan\theta)^2\frac{dh}{dt} = k\sqrt{h}
$$